# I noticed a relation between the cosines of $0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$ and the square roots of $4, 3, 2, 1, 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, square-numbers

> Yesterday I've noticed some relationships with cosine and square root. Anything interesting about it?

I was trying to find the smallest width on an hexagon with radius $1.0$ and I noticed that I could get it both by $\sqrt 3$ and the or two times the cosine of $30^\circ$.

[image]

I wondered if there would be more matches and so I notice these even though might look silly...

$$\begin{align}
2 \cos 90^\circ &= \sqrt 0 \\
2 \cos 60^\circ &= \sqrt 1 \\
2 \cos 45^\circ &= \sqrt 2 \\
2 \cos 30^\circ &= \sqrt 3 \\
2 \cos \phantom{9}0^\circ &= \sqrt 4
\end{align}$$

Is there anything interesting to know about these?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it doesn't look silly at all.  It's a well known mnemonic of some important values of $\cos$ and $\sin$ as well.

Comment: You might notice that the pattern is not as regular as it first seems. The angle difference between $\sqrt 0$ and $\sqrt 1$ and between $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 4$ is $30^\circ$, but the angle differences between $\sqrt 1, \sqrt 2,\sqrt 3$ are $15^\circ$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair
You can see here the graph of the function $f(x) = (sin(x)*2)**2)
http://i.imgur.com/5qrACzH.png

Comment: Also: http://i.imgur.com/GLBPzVN.png

Comment: @probiner - I'm sorry, but what was the point of posting those pictures? I can assure that I am quite well aware of what the graphs of trig function (and their squares) look like.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm sure probiner didn't mean to offend/patronise, remember (s)he doesn't know what your level of knowledge is...

Comment: @Kevin - I was not accusing probiner of offense or patronizing. I was curious what probiner had intended to communicate by posting these graphs. Those pictures were apparently motivated by my comment above. But I have no idea at all what that motivation was - why it was that these two graphs should have any useful bearing on my comment. So I was hoping to get some sort of explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This rules we used in high school with fingers do apply for both sine and cosine see the pictures

[image]

See also the following

[image]

Comment: Cheers for the memorabilia :)

Answer (score 18):

Your list is sometimes given in trig books as a mnemonic device.  Looking a little deeper the pattern that the angles in a regular $n$-gon give algebraic values for the $\cos$ function is showing itself, though the pattern of simple surds does not continue, e.g. $\cos (\frac{2\pi}{5})=\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{5}-1)$

Comment: Did you end your answer?
 Looks cut. Someone mentioned this to me: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/specang.htm

Comment: @probiner thanks for pointing out the dangling conjunction.  I was thinking about mentioning DeMoivre's Theorem but got interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The last figure was also teached to me mnemotecnically to memorize the value of trigonometric functions on certain angles, notice that you can also calculate the tangent by ignoring dividing 2 this way:

Take the 0 and the 4 of the fist column (0 radians), divide and take the root, you have: $tan (0)= \sqrt(\dfrac{0}{4})=0$

For the second column we have $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, take the 1 and the 3, divide and take the root again: $tan (\dfrac{\pi}{6})=\sqrt(\dfrac{1}{3})=\dfrac{\sqrt(1)}{\sqrt(3)}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

Similarily, $tan(\dfrac{\pi}{4})=\sqrt(\dfrac{2}{2})=\sqrt(1)=1$

$tan(\dfrac{\pi}{3})=\sqrt(\dfrac{3}{1})=\sqrt 3$

Finally, take for the 4th column ($\dfrac{\pi}{2}$) 4 and $0$.  $tan(\dfrac{\pi}{2})=\sqrt(\dfrac{4}{0})!$ wich is in agreement of the fact that $tan$ is not defined on $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and thus cannot be.

Answer (score 0):

They're part of the constructible numbers. If you were given a perfectly straight ruler, that has no markings and has a length R, and was told to use that to draw a straight line that is the length qR, where q is some irrational number, then in general that's impossible.

However, the constructible numbers are a subset of the irrational numbers that are the exempt from the rule. If you had a compass, you could mark points to construct triangles that forms a length qR as part of its structure. Basically it means that certain irrational values can be drawn using rational values.

You'll notice that all triangles that can be formed as a combination of those angles (60-60-60, 45-45-90, 30-60-90) has at least one of its sides that is a unit length. There's a bunch more applications to this in some heavier theory stuff related algebraic topology, Bravais lattice structures, etc if you really wanted to dig deep into it.

Maybe this helps?