# Why is $\cos(45°) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \simeq 0.7071$ rather than $0.5$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to wrap my head around trigonometry.
Working in degrees we get:

$$\cos(0°) = 1$$

$$\cos(90°) = 0$$

Half way between $0$ and $90$ degrees we get $45$ degrees, so it seems logical to me that $\cos(45°)$ would give $0.5$, but instead we get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \simeq 0.7071$, why is that?

Comment: Because $cos$ is not linear

Comment: $\cos(45)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Your reasoning would be correct if cosine was linear. However, we can see that it is concave down.

Comment: Try applying your reasoning to the function $x^2$: $1$ is halfway between $0$ and $2$, so $1^2$ should be half of $2^2=4$.

Comment: May this help you better you self-learning: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2340349

Comment: @KristofferHelander  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ , $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is **not** a linear function, so that assumption that you made will not hold. Note that the value $0.7071$ is not far away from $0.5$ because of the curved line that the $\cos$ function follows on the cartesian coordinate system, which isn't widely deviated from the line $y=x$. This **does not** mean that other non-linear functions will have "middle-point" values close to $0.5$ (that entirely depends on their polynomial approximation).

Check a simple graph down below :

[image]

Also checking the series representation of the cosine $\cos$ function, one can see that is clear that :

$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

has **non-linear** terms.

Comment: This is clearly a good answer to OP problem. it is exactly what troubles the OP+1:)

Comment: @Rebellos could you please elaborate on that last formula there, because I think that is why I can't wrap my hand around this; I only understand _one side_ of this. $\cos(\theta)$ is simply adjacent / hypotenuse, and you get a fraction, but converting an angle to a fraction, that seems much more complicated; so what magic is actually happening when you type $\cos(45°)$ into a calculator?

Comment: @KristofferHelander Since there is much talk to be made around this subject, [take a look on a post discussing that right here !](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185356/rigorous-proof-of-the-taylor-expansions-of-sin-x-and-cos-x)

Comment: @Rebellos Yes, after doing some research it seems to me that this is a much more complicated matter. I have marked your post as the answear because in order to truly understand this I'll probably have to dig a lot deeper, but I'll do that with other questions another time :) Your answear gives a good basic understanding to start with, thank you very much!

Comment: @KristofferHelander No problem and yes, proving that this is the series describing the $\cos$ function isn't such a simple task. I'm happy to have helped you !

Answer (score 4):

That kind of linear intrapolation requires that you are dealing with a linear function, but you're not. That is, your reasoning would work if the function looked like a triangular see-saw:

[image]

But the cosine function doesn't look like that ... see Rebellos' post! (we make a good team!)

Answer (score 2):

For right-angled triangles, where one of the angles is $x\neq90^{\circ}$, I'm sure you know that $\cos x$ is the adjacent side length divided by the length of the hypotenuse.

A right-angled triangle with angle $45^{\circ}$ has opposite and adjacent sides equal in length, so by Pythagoras's Theorem, the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{2}$ times the length of the adjacent side. It follows that $\cos 45^{\circ}=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ X \in [0°,90°] $$
Are just the inputs to the function $$ f(\color{red}{x}) = \cos(\color{red}{x}), \ x \in X $$.

And $ 45° $ is the mid point of the input, Why it should be necessary that the output is also the mid point?

Consider $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $$ Start inputting $ x= {{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}}$

Here also, $$ f(\color{green}{1}) =  \color{green}{1} $$ 
Now, mid point of input is $5$.
But $$ f(\color{green}{5}) = \frac{1}{\color{green}{5}}≠5 $$

---

So we conclude that it may happen that $\sin(\color{green}{0°}) = \color{green}{0} $ but there is not a direct relation/pattern between this sine or cosine function with its output (range).

Comment: This is exactly what trouble the OP +1:)

Comment: @Guy Fsone I really appreciate your compliment :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the trigonometric circle, for an angle of 45 degrees $cos\theta$ is the side of a square with diagonal with length equal to 1 thus it’s equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

To better visualize take a look to the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a square triangle with angles 90, 45, 45, it is obvious by symmetry that the adjacent and opposite sides are equal; assume they are $1$.

By the pythagorean theorem, the hypotenuse is $h=\sqrt {1^2+1^2}=\sqrt2$. Then $h\,\cos45=1$, so $$\cos45=\frac1h=\frac1 {\sqrt2}. $$

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^2$ satisfies $f(0)=1, f(1)=1$, and half way between it is $1/\sqrt{2}$, and maybe that's why $\cos$ is also $1/\sqrt{2}$ half way between.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear from this picture that $\cos 45^\circ > 0.5$

[image]